# dbpedia NLP dataset used for Named entity extraction

Tags: nlp, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I went through their github files as well as the official site, I can't find the named entity tagging training corpus they used in splotlight.

How Can I found the dataset  instead of a trained model?

Comment: Have you tried to check the repo https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/model-quickstarter ?

Comment: I found the exact guide on ner dataset here: https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/pignlproc. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it so that this question no longer comes up as unanswered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see This link https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Web-service

In here, method for setting up dbpedia lookup offline is explained. Also they have given 4 tar files which are

- redirects_en.nt
- short_abstracts_en.nt
- instance_types_en.nt
- article_categories_en.nt

these are supposed to be training data for it.

Comment: The link you refer to provides guide on using dbpedia-spotlight services, I didn't find any information on how to generate NER training corpus. It's true we can use the 4 tar files to generate ourselves, but the whole parsing process is time consuming and more importantly, it's not part of our core logic. So I was looking forward to a tool to generate ner training data as I posted before(http://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/pignlproc)